# WPF Cefsharp instance/object reference in class not working

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am spending too much time trying to solve this issue: i am trying to create a Core, because the project is already confusing me and it is not that big. The Core is a Class outside the main Thread. On the main Thread i named the Browser, browser :

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

In the class i call it like this:

```
 public class Core : MainWindow
{

    public void winstenVerlies()
    {
        var currentdirectory = "https://www.google.nl";
        this.browser.Address = currentdirectory;

    }
}
```

I have tried numerous ways, this is the way i like it but they all give me the same message:

> "object reference is not set on an instance of an object."

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happened to the call to InitializeComponent?

Comment: It was behaving naughty so i removed it. gave me a error message.

Comment: The `InitializeComponent` initializes your 'browser'. When you try to call it, it is `null`. Therefore: 'object reference is not set to an instance of an object'.

Comment: I have it initiated like this on the top
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      
            private void Mainwindow_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: The error message seems to have dissappeared... InitializeComponent(); does not give me a error at the moment.

Comment: Haha check out the error message it gave me!

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: I think you should spend some time figuring out how WPF works.

Comment: I have InitializeComponent(); now inside Mainwindow_Initialized and it is giving me no errors, the message of the class is still the same "object reference is not set on an instance of an object."

Comment: The `browser` object is still probably null, can you confirm? Does the `Core` constructor properly call the base constructor you are talking about? And you really need to check how WPF works with MVVM structure... seeing a "core" definition at the view level gives me nightmares.

Comment: I have found the problem, everything works fine and is set the way it should be. this is causing the problem.
browser.RegisterJsObject("callbackObj", new CallbackObjectForJs());

Comment: I can not use anything this is a Javascript hybrid nothing works with out browser.RegisterJsObject("callbackObj", new CallbackObjectForJs());

Comment: So basically it has nothing to do with the code you provided, and we had no chance to solve the problem. Next time, please read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Eh... you think i knew this?... i found the problem becouse of the initialComponent issue.. this is my first application in WPF...

Comment: It has everything todo with the code that i provide. becouse both in the recommended place are causing a infinite loop... and i dont know why, i am in the middle of figuring it out, when i first placed the callBackObj i got this error message, i dissabled initiateComponent and totally forgot about it.

Comment: The problems still remains. "object reference is not set on an instance of an object." with or with out callBackObj/InitializeComponent ...

Comment: Post the *full* definition of your Core class please.

Comment: This is the full definition of the Core, i cant add any more becouse i am stuck on this problem, only thing i left out is the namespace, all the working parts are still on the main Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. i researched it for weeks now, from what i can see is the problem is the root, when i use this or the object/function name when calling it, it does not get passed the root of the class, instead of the root of the project. here is how you bypass it.
pass the object trough the class.

```
 public void  winstenVerlies(ChromiumWebBrowser b)
    {

       var currentdirectory = "https://www.google.nl";
       b.Address = currentdirectory;

    }
```

then call it like so.

```
Core Menu = new Core();
Menu.winstenVerlies(browser);
```

Now i try'd this befor, it gave me error messages the last time, i did not trace the source of the problems.
All i know is it working now, and i am happy.
Have a nice day.